# How i get same data from multiple lists and insert them into a listbox

Tags: python, api, tkinter

Im trying to make really basic COVID19 case tracker i already have a code but it only works when i entered countries that i want to see COVID919 stats its not useful thats why i need a listbox of countries then i can pick .I need list of all countries and i found an API but i don't know how to get only Countries in that API i tried something but it only give me one country. so how can i get all countries from this API and insert them into a listbox one by one .

```
import requests
import json

api_url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/countries'

data = requests.get(api_url)
data = json.loads(data.text)
print(data[0]['Country'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so:

```
countries = [item["Country"] for item in data]
print(countries)
# ['Bangladesh', 'Ireland', 'New Zealand', ... 'South Africa', 'Taiwan, Republic of China']
```

So, you can add it to a `tkinter.ListBox` like so:

```
from tkinter import *  


top = Tk()  
top.geometry("200x250")  
lbl = Label(top,text = "Countries...")  
listbox = Listbox(top)  

for i, country in enumerate(sorted(countries)):
    listbox.insert(i+1, country)

lbl.pack()  
listbox.pack()  
top.mainloop()
```

Which produces something like so:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help firstly . What about inserting these to a listbox is there a way to insert these one by one

Comment: What do you mean by a **listbox**?

Comment: i mean tkinter listbox like that [link](https://prnt.sc/t460fg)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import json

api_url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/countries'

data = requests.get(api_url)
data = json.loads(data.text)
conlis=[]
for con in data:
    conlis.append(con['Country'])
print(conlis)
```

Output will be,

```
[u'Bangladesh', u'Ireland', u'New Zealand', u'Serbia', u'Spain', u'Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands', u'Colombia', u'Holy See (Vatican City State)', u'Hong Kong, SAR China', u'Malawi', u'Costa Rica', u'Gibraltar', u'Latvia', u'Mayotte', u'Northern Mariana Islands', u'Argentina', u'Cambodia', u'Pakistan', u'Papua New Guinea', u'Peru', u'Sao Tome and Principe', u'Saudi Arabia', u'Sudan', u'Australia', u'Nigeria', u'United Kingdom', u'Anguilla', u'Djibouti', u'Qatar', u'Bulgaria', u'Czech Republic', u'Ecuador', u'Guadeloupe', u'Jordan', u'Senegal', u'Dominica', u'Congo (Kinshasa)', u'Kazakhstan', u'Macao, SAR China', u'Swaziland', u'Canada', u'Faroe Islands', u'Sierra Leone', u'Uganda', u'US Minor Outlying Islands', u'Virgin Islands, US', u'Antarctica', u'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands', u'Greenland', u'ALA Aland Islands', u'Algeria', u'Guernsey', u'Madagascar', u'Rwanda', u'Burundi', u'Chad', u'Monaco', u'Togo', u'United States of America', u'Cayman Islands', u'Cocos (Keeling) Islands', u'Congo (Brazzaville)', u'Slovenia', u'Israel', u'Jersey', u'Tokelau', u'Belgium', u'Cameroon', u'Fiji', u'Kenya', u'Kyrgyzstan', u'Slovakia', u'Botswana', u'Saint-Barth\xe9lemy', u'Tuvalu', u'French Polynesia', u'Uzbekistan', u'Belarus', u'Croatia', u'Ghana', u'Haiti', u'Libya', u'Panama', u'Zambia', u'Cyprus', u'Niue', u'Somalia', u'France', u'Austria', u'Bahamas', u'Denmark', u'Mozambique', u'Bosnia and Herzegovina', u'China', u'Honduras', u'Mauritania', u'Dominican Republic', u'Guatemala', u'Saint-Martin (French part)', u'Lithuania', u'Martinique', u'Puerto Rico', u'Bolivia', u'Egypt', u'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)', u'Hungary', u'Portugal', u'Saint Pierre and Miquelon', u'Marshall Islands', u'Morocco', u'Netherlands Antilles', u'Pitcairn', u'Solomon Islands', u'Central African Republic', u'Mali', u'Tunisia', u'Turkey', u'French Guiana', u'Korea (South)', u'Lao PDR', u'Thailand', u'Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic)', u'Brunei Darussalam', u'Christmas Island', u'Germany', u'Philippines', u'Saint Vincent and Grenadines', u'Singapore', u'Syrian Arab Republic (Syria)', u'American Samoa', u'Iran, Islamic Republic of', u'Nauru', u'Albania', u'British Indian Ocean Territory', u'Ethiopia', u'Lesotho', u'Nicaragua', u'Western Sahara', u'Guinea-Bissau', u'Seychelles', u'Barbados', u'Burkina Faso', u'Cape Verde', u'Comoros', u'Heard and Mcdonald Islands', u'Wallis and Futuna Islands', u'Bouvet Island', u'Cook Islands', u'Guinea', u'Lebanon', u'Tonga', u'Zimbabwe', u'Netherlands', u'Switzerland', u'Vanuatu', u'Bhutan', u'Mauritius', u'Russian Federation', u'Turkmenistan', u'British Virgin Islands', u'Gabon', u'Liberia', u'Myanmar', u'Saint Kitts and Nevis', u'Malaysia', u'Palestinian Territory', u'South Sudan', u'Armenia', u'San Marino', u'Tanzania, United Republic of', u'Bahrain', u'Bermuda', u'Greece', u'Ukraine', u'Afghanistan', u'Chile', u'Finland', u'French Southern Territories', u'Georgia', u'Isle of Man', u'Mexico', u'Namibia', u'Eritrea', u'Mongolia', u'Romania', u'Benin', u'Brazil', u'Guam', u'Moldova', u'Andorra', u"C\xf4te d'Ivoire", u'Japan', u'Kiribati', u'Malta', u'Paraguay', u'Sweden', u'Jamaica', u'Nepal', u'Sri Lanka', u'Republic of Kosovo', u'Estonia', u'Iraq', u'Iceland', u'New Caledonia', u'Saint Lucia', u'Samoa', u'United Arab Emirates', u'Belize', u'Liechtenstein', u'Palau', u'Poland', u'R\xe9union', u'Tajikistan', u'Timor-Leste', u'Uruguay', u'Antigua and Barbuda', u'Niger', u'Oman', u'Viet Nam', u'Luxembourg', u'Micronesia, Federated States of', u'Norway', u'Saint Helena', u'Turks and Caicos Islands', u'Gambia', u'India', u'Trinidad and Tobago', u'Indonesia', u'Macedonia, Republic of', u'Suriname', u'Azerbaijan', u'Guyana', u'Maldives', u'Montserrat', u'Aruba', u'Equatorial Guinea', u'Italy', u'El Salvador', u'Montenegro', u'Yemen', u'Angola', u'Korea (North)', u'Kuwait', u'Cuba', u'Grenada', u'Norfolk Island', u'South Africa', u'Taiwan, Republic of China']
```

If you want country names in ascii.you can try

```
import requests
import json

api_url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/countries'

data = requests.get(api_url)
data = json.loads(data.text)
conlis=[]
for con in data:
    conlis.append(con['Country'].encode("ascii","ignore"))
print(conlis)
```

output will be,

```
['Bangladesh', 'Ireland', 'New Zealand', 'Serbia', 'Spain', 'Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands', 'Colombia', 'Holy See (Vatican City State)', 'Hong Kong, SAR China', 'Malawi', 'Costa Rica', 'Gibraltar', 'Latvia', 'Mayotte', 'Northern Mariana Islands', 'Argentina', 'Cambodia', 'Pakistan', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Peru', 'Sao Tome and Principe', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Sudan', 'Australia', 'Nigeria', 'United Kingdom', 'Anguilla', 'Djibouti', 'Qatar', 'Bulgaria', 'Czech Republic', 'Ecuador', 'Guadeloupe', 'Jordan', 'Senegal', 'Dominica', 'Congo (Kinshasa)', 'Kazakhstan', 'Macao, SAR China', 'Swaziland', 'Canada', 'Faroe Islands', 'Sierra Leone', 'Uganda', 'US Minor Outlying Islands', 'Virgin Islands, US', 'Antarctica', 'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands', 'Greenland', 'ALA Aland Islands', 'Algeria', 'Guernsey', 'Madagascar', 'Rwanda', 'Burundi', 'Chad', 'Monaco', 'Togo', 'United States of America', 'Cayman Islands', 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands', 'Congo (Brazzaville)', 'Slovenia', 'Israel', 'Jersey', 'Tokelau', 'Belgium', 'Cameroon', 'Fiji', 'Kenya', 'Kyrgyzstan', 'Slovakia', 'Botswana', 'Saint-Barthlemy', 'Tuvalu', 'French Polynesia', 'Uzbekistan', 'Belarus', 'Croatia', 'Ghana', 'Haiti', 'Libya', 'Panama', 'Zambia', 'Cyprus', 'Niue', 'Somalia', 'France', 'Austria', 'Bahamas', 'Denmark', 'Mozambique', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'China', 'Honduras', 'Mauritania', 'Dominican Republic', 'Guatemala', 'Saint-Martin (French part)', 'Lithuania', 'Martinique', 'Puerto Rico', 'Bolivia', 'Egypt', 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)', 'Hungary', 'Portugal', 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon', 'Marshall Islands', 'Morocco', 'Netherlands Antilles', 'Pitcairn', 'Solomon Islands', 'Central African Republic', 'Mali', 'Tunisia', 'Turkey', 'French Guiana', 'Korea (South)', 'Lao PDR', 'Thailand', 'Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic)', 'Brunei Darussalam', 'Christmas Island', 'Germany', 'Philippines', 'Saint Vincent and Grenadines', 'Singapore', 'Syrian Arab Republic (Syria)', 'American Samoa', 'Iran, Islamic Republic of', 'Nauru', 'Albania', 'British Indian Ocean Territory', 'Ethiopia', 'Lesotho', 'Nicaragua', 'Western Sahara', 'Guinea-Bissau', 'Seychelles', 'Barbados', 'Burkina Faso', 'Cape Verde', 'Comoros', 'Heard and Mcdonald Islands', 'Wallis and Futuna Islands', 'Bouvet Island', 'Cook Islands', 'Guinea', 'Lebanon', 'Tonga', 'Zimbabwe', 'Netherlands', 'Switzerland', 'Vanuatu', 'Bhutan', 'Mauritius', 'Russian Federation', 'Turkmenistan', 'British Virgin Islands', 'Gabon', 'Liberia', 'Myanmar', 'Saint Kitts and Nevis', 'Malaysia', 'Palestinian Territory', 'South Sudan', 'Armenia', 'San Marino', 'Tanzania, United Republic of', 'Bahrain', 'Bermuda', 'Greece', 'Ukraine', 'Afghanistan', 'Chile', 'Finland', 'French Southern Territories', 'Georgia', 'Isle of Man', 'Mexico', 'Namibia', 'Eritrea', 'Mongolia', 'Romania', 'Benin', 'Brazil', 'Guam', 'Moldova', 'Andorra', "Cte d'Ivoire", 'Japan', 'Kiribati', 'Malta', 'Paraguay', 'Sweden', 'Jamaica', 'Nepal', 'Sri Lanka', 'Republic of Kosovo', 'Estonia', 'Iraq', 'Iceland', 'New Caledonia', 'Saint Lucia', 'Samoa', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Belize', 'Liechtenstein', 'Palau', 'Poland', 'Runion', 'Tajikistan', 'Timor-Leste', 'Uruguay', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Niger', 'Oman', 'Viet Nam', 'Luxembourg', 'Micronesia, Federated States of', 'Norway', 'Saint Helena', 'Turks and Caicos Islands', 'Gambia', 'India', 'Trinidad and Tobago', 'Indonesia', 'Macedonia, Republic of', 'Suriname', 'Azerbaijan', 'Guyana', 'Maldives', 'Montserrat', 'Aruba', 'Equatorial Guinea', 'Italy', 'El Salvador', 'Montenegro', 'Yemen', 'Angola', 'Korea (North)', 'Kuwait', 'Cuba', 'Grenada', 'Norfolk Island', 'South Africa', 'Taiwan, Republic of China']
```

I think you  are asking that,

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import json

api_url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/countries'

data = requests.get(api_url)
data = json.loads(data.text)
top = Tk() 
listbox = Listbox(top) 
label = Label(top, text="Country Selection")
i=1
for con in data:
    listbox.insert(i,con['Country'].encode("ascii","ignore"))
    i+=1 

label.pack()
listbox.pack() 
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: is there any way to insert these countries to a tkinter listbox [link](https://prnt.sc/t460fg) like that

Comment: I think ,you are asking that,

Comment: from tkinter import *
import requests
import json

api_url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/countries'

data = requests.get(api_url)
data = json.loads(data.text)
top = Tk() 
listbox = Listbox(top) 
label = Label(top, text="Country Selection")
i=1
for con in data:
    listbox.insert(i,con['Country'].encode("ascii","ignore"))
    i+=1 

label.pack()
listbox.pack() 
top.mainloop()

Answer (score 0):

you can use map as well it return list of countries:

"""

```
   import requests
   import json

   api_url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/countries'
   data = requests.get(api_url)
   data = json.loads(data.text)
   output = map(lambda x: x['Country'], data)
   print output
```

"""

output will be list of country.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
import json
from tkinter import *

api_url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/countries'

#Create a tkinter window and Listbox
window=Tk()
#Setup defaults
window.geometry("400x300")
window.title("COVID Tracker")

#Create a listbox
myListbox=Listbox(window)
myListbox.pack(expand=True)

#Get Data
data = requests.get(api_url)
data = json.loads(data.text)

#Parse into a listbox
for d in data:
    myListbox.insert(data.index(d),d['Country'])


window.mainloop()
```

Here is an example of how to Parse the list of countries from the API into a tkinter Listbox.